# how is the DOM constructed in the browser (IE or FF) or how javascript traps object hierarchy

Tags: javascript, dom, client-server

Would some please send me the link for any articles , which explains , how DOM is constructed in the browser after the response is received from server

Comment: What specifically do you want to know? The general answer is fairly trivial: the document is parsed, and objects are created.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific.
The browser spits off the response as html. Then  how does javascript captilises on the object hierarchy once the response is available at the client side. how can it identify the parents and siblings . 
kinda how is it implemented any ideas.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dave Hyatt, who used to work on Gecko (used by Firefox and others) at Mozilla and now works on WebKit (used by Safari, Chrome and others) has an [old blog post](http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/hyatt/archives/2004_05.html#005496) explaining some of the complexities of this process.

He has also written in more depth about the rendering process in a series of five articles; the [first one mentions some aspects of DOM parsing](http://webkit.org/blog/114/webcore-rendering-i-the-basics/), but all five are great reading if you're curious about how a browser actually works.

Answer (score 3):

Read up on [Trident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_%28layout_engine%29), [Gecko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_layout_engine) and [Webkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webkit) - three very popular layout engines. To really understand how these function, a post titled [How Browsers Work: Behind the scenes of modern web browsers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/) was published on HTML5 Rocks some time back. It goes deep into the inner-workings.

Comment: And Gecko, since he asked about FF: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_(layout_engine)